# Master Password Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-security

I have a question about Spring Security. I want to put a master password for all users.

How can i do this?

I use Spring Security 3.0.3.

Comment: youd could implement your own authentication provider where you have that kind of logic. Or you could write a custom user details service where could introduce that behaviour. http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/userDetailsService.html

Comment: You shouldn't be using 3.0.3, as it has [known vulnerabilities](http://support.springsource.com/security/spring-security).

Comment: What do you mean by a master password?